# Subfigures in a0poster

Tags: graphics, subfloats, posters, a0poster

I am working on a poster for a scientific conference using the `a0poster` document type (with 3 equally spaced columns), but it seems that images/figures are not easy to work with. When I include the following code, I don't receive any error messages, but my images just don't show up.

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{test1.png}
    \subcaption{Test 1}\label{subfig-1:dummy}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{test2.png}
    \subcaption{Test 2}\label{subfig-2:dummy}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Blablabla}
  \label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}
```

I expected an output like this:
[image]

I can't seem to figure out what could be wrong, besides perhaps that `\begin{figure}` does not work on `a0poster`. [This](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=23576) is where I found the code above.

EDIT: I am using the appropriate packages `float`, `graphicx`, and `subcaption`.

EDIT2: Just figured out that floats are not compatible with the `multicols` environment. Is there something similar that I can do to achieve a similar look?

Comment: Please, convert your code snippet into complete small document --
 beginning with \documentclass{...} and end with \end{document} --which we can copy and compile.  Help us to help you!